# How to write a subquery from dataset in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, collections, dataset, subquery

### Dataset

```
[
     {
        "agent_id": "D01",
        "amount": "2"
     },
     {
        "agent_id": "D01",
        "amount": "2"
     },
     {
        "agent_id": "A01",
        "amount": "1"
     },
     {
        "agent_id": "A01",
        "amount": "1"
     },
    
]
```

### **Expected Result**

```
[
     {
        "agent_id": "D01",
        "amount": "4"
     },
     {
        "agent_id": "A01",
        "amount": "2"
     },
   
]
```

Hello, there is an original dataset with 4 collections as shown above. I was try to transform the data with group by `agent_id` and sum of the `amount`. 
I was plan to using sub query likes `select agent_id, sum(amount) from (Dataset) group by agent_id`, however I have no idea how to achieve it in laravel sub query. Can anyone guide me or and provide some suggestion. Appreciate it.

Comment: usually, when it comes to complicated query, might want to build it yourself and use `DB::raw`  to execute it.  ( [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods) )

Comment: @Nicolas thanks for your reply, but the result  data is retrieve fom the dataset not table

Comment: Do you mean using collections? You can use something like `Collection::reduce()`

Comment: @HazemMohamed hello thansk for your suggestion. Could you help me to show some example? because i tried just now but still not able to achieve it with the group by

Comment: Please check @Donkarnash's answer which is actually great and a very good example

Answer (score 5):

If the data is provided via a dataset or an api call then you can use Laravel Collection methods to manipulate and get the desired output

```php
//Assuming that the data is in array format
$output = collect($data)
  ->groupBy('agent_id')
  ->map(
    fn($records, $agent) => ['agent_id' => $agent, 'amount' => $records->sum('amount')]
  )
  ->values()->all();
```